# Getting Angularjs ng-view to work

Tags: angularjs, json

I am trying to figure out how to build a SPA with angularjs. My routes are working and each partial page is loading in ng-view properly. I'm trying to load external json data. I had it working onnce but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. The goal is to list products and have a details page for each product. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Here's my code:

app.js

```
var myApp = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);
myApp.config(['$routeProvider','$locationProvider',    function($routeProvider,$locationProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
        when('/home',{
            templateUrl: 'partials/home.html',
            controller: "storeCtrl"
        }).
        when('/about',{
            templateUrl: 'partials/about.html',
            controller: "storeCtrl"
        }).
        when('/computers',{
            templateUrl: 'partials/computers.html',
            controller: "storeCtrl"
        }).
        when('/smartphones',{
            templateUrl: 'partials/smartphones.html',
            controller: "storeCtrl"
        }).
        when('/tablets',{
            templateUrl: 'partials/tablets.html',
            controller: "storeCtrl"
        }).
        otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/home'             
        });
    }]);

myApp.controller('storeCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {


$scope.homeHeading = 'Home';
$scope.aboutHeading = 'About Us';
$scope.computersHeading = 'Computers';
$scope.smartphonesHeading = 'Smartphones';
$scope.tabletsHeading = 'Tablets';

$http.get('products.json').success(function(data) {
    $scope.products = data;

});
console.log($scope.products);

}]);
```

computers.html

```
<div ng-controller="storeCtrl">
<h1>{{computersHeading}}</h1>

<div ng-repeat="item in products">
<p>{{ item.name }}</p>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: What do you expect to happen, and what happens instead? Note that you shouldn't have `ng-controller="storeCtrl"`: you have already defined which controller the partial should have in your route configuration.

Comment: Any error that you are getting?

Comment: What I'm expecting to happen is for my products in the json file to be listed using ng-repeat. When I try to access and item attribute for example {{item.name}} nothing happens. In the view I see the curly brackets and it's contents.

Comment: @RahulArora i'm not getting any errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try this

```
$http.get('products.json').then(function(result) {
$scope.products = result.data;

});
```

And remove ng-controller from the view as you have already defined it in myApp.config()

Comment: I removed the ng-controller from each partial page and I tried your solution, my partials still work but my json data isn't coming in. Here's the link to the project: www.jewebdevlop.com/angularpractice

Comment: your link is not working. can you provide me full code.

Comment: I can't see your whole code by viewing page source . You have to provide me code to know what is happening. can you provide me your json file. There is error in your Json file. path is incorrect for your json file or its name.. Its shoeing error 404 not found.

Comment: just by reading your comment I found my mistakes, I changed the path to js/products.json and I validated my json and it's working. Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `$http.get` service which returns a promise object.